# Maximum principle and a differential inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

Let $z:[0,T]\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfy the following differential inequality$$
\frac{d}{dt}z(t)\leq f(z(t))
$$
where $f$ is a continuous real-valued function. Now, let $y$ be a solution to the equality case, i.e, a solution to the ODE$$
\frac{d}{dt}y(t)=f(y(t)).
$$
Assuming $x(0)\leq y(0)$, my goal is to apply the maximum principle to conclude that$$
z(t)\leq y(t)
$$
for all $t$. So far, I have been unable to conclude anything due to the generality of $f$, but I might be missing something. Any ideas?

Comment: I know about  maximum principles for holomorphic and for harmonic functions. Which maximum principle are you thinking of here which can be applied to real-valued functions on an interval?

Comment: For each $t > t_0$, the function $y(t) = (\max(t-t_0, 0))^2$ solves $y'(t) = 2\sqrt{y(t)}$, $y(0) = 0$, which means that your conclusion does not hold in general. Assuming a *strict* inequality of the initial values makes it work, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Correction: I meant "For each $t_0 > 0 $ ..."

Comment: Using $y'=\sqrt{|y|}$ solutions can cross due to non-uniqueness on the constant solution $y=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a proof, just a sketch of how to think about the problem:

Try looking at the problem in the phase plane: $z$ on the $x$ axis and $dz/dt$ on the $y$ axis.  Plot $f(z)$ on the graph and realize that positive points higher on the graph move to the right faster than positive points lower on the graph.  Similarly, negative points very low move to the left faster than negative points higher up.  Thus, any initial point that starts below $f(z)$ will move right slower than a point on $f(z)$ and move left faster than a point on $f(z)$.  Thus, any initial point $z(0)\le y(0)$ must satisfy $z(t)\le y(t)$.